# Convert SQL Command to lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda

If possible, please guide me how to convert my SQL command to lambda expression

```
select d.* from takcontractdet d where d.contractid=pubcontractid and d.personid in
(
select p.id from personel p where p.parentid=pubparentid)
)
```

Comment: You need to at least make a start on this, this isn't a code writing service I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two query

```
var personelIds = Personels.Where(p => p.ParentId == pubparentid)
                                   .Select(e => e.Id).ToList();

var result = Takcontractdets.Where(d => d.contractid == pubcontractid && 
             personelIds.Contains(d.PersonId)).ToList();
```

One query

```
var result = Takcontractdets.Where(d => d.contractid == pubcontractid && 
             Personels.Where(p => p.ParentId == pubparentid)
                      .Select(e => e.Id).ToList().Contains(d.PersonId))
             .ToList();
```